# Why is notACalendarUser error is thrown when listing a user's calendar?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to run an API call for CalendarList.list (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list) for a user, but I consistently get an error returned:

```
    {
      domain: 'calendar',
      reason: 'notACalendarUser',
      message: 'The user must be signed up for Google Calendar.'
    }
```

The user is a valid Google Calendar user, so I can't fathom why I would get this error. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is  the email that you are using a Google account?

Comment: In this case the email is a hosted domain using Google Calendar

Comment: by that do you mean that the user can go to calendar.google.com and sign-in with that user/email?

Comment: Yep that's correct, they can sign in just fine on calendar.google.com. By hosted domain I mean their email has a custom domain, so it's not username@gmail.com, for instance.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the user had calendar enable, I know that when calendar is not enable for the user, that error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. First on March 11.
It was with a @alumni.ncsu.edu email. I tried a different hosted domain and it still works though.

I couldn't retry getting consent for calendar scopes for that same email. Can you test? I suspect Google changed any policy of them about calendars. IMO it would be a problem if they still grant permission for those scope.

My action was revoking the user integration if they don't have access to it.

Google is very annoying sometimes. I wish they'd email us API changes.